# Use Curl PhP5.6 instead of Curl PhP7

Tags: php, linux, curl, debian, php-5.6

After compiling manually the version 5.6 of PhP on Debian 9 i need to install the curl for that version too but the problem is i don't see any lib on the repositories for PhP5 (?):

```
apt-cache search php | grep -i curl

php-curl - CURL module for PHP [default]
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
```

I need the curl for PhP5.6 to be used as default curl instead of PhP7 ( requirement for website who is already using PhP5.6 instead of PhP7 ).

Any idea where i can get that curl version and set it as default ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you compile manually that means you need to compile/include the libraries manually too. Check http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php (it's not hard, you just need to add a `--with-curl` option)

Comment: After launching the configure again with the --with-curl option i get the  configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
    easy.h should be in <curl-dir>/include/curl error, after that i've found that easy.h and added the --with-curl-dir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl but it returns me at the end configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-curl-dir so, how i can specify the file dir on that option?

Comment: that means you don't actually have the cURL library installed and therefore can't configure PHP to use it. All PHP dependencies need to be installed for configure to succeed

Comment: libcurl4-gnutls-dev ya está en su versión más reciente (7.52.1-5+deb9u3).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
(That means it's already installed).

curl -V
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1

Comment: Hi, the convention here is to always add answers separate from the question, rather than editing them into place, even if it's your question. That way, every Q&A has the same format, and the software can know which questions have answers and show them differently to future users.

Comment: Didn't know that, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP5.6 and its dependency can be found on  [Ondřej Surý repository](https://deb.sury.org/). PHP5.6 is already installed on your system , you can install a single package `php5.6-curl` as follow:

```
apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt update
apt install php5.6-curl
```

> I need the curl for PhP5.6 to be used as default curl instead of PhP7.

You should add the PHP5.6 to `update-alternative` , it will be used later to switch between the installed php version.

let's say the `php5.6` is configured to be installed under `/usr/bin/php5.6` , the configuration commands should be:

Adding PHP5.6 to `update-alternatives`:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/php5.6 90
```

Set PHP5.6 as default:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

or you can use:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

Then select `php5.6`.

The best way is to install the `php5.6` and its dependency from Ondřej Surý repository , when a php5.6 update is available , it will be installed through `apt`.